# how to add additional query after link path

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am sending link to email address for password reset functionality and after sometime i want this link to expire. for that i have created a token(which is encrytped using a key) and expire-date and i want to put these as query in my email link but i don't know to do it.
this is how i use token class in *forgotPassword* Post method.

```
var tokenModel = new LinkExpire();
                tokenModel.ExpiresOn = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
                tokenModel.CreateToken = TokenHelperMethods.GetToken(tokenModel);
```

this is my link code.

```
string resetCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var varifyUrl = "/E_HealthCare_Web/Account/ResetPassword/" + resetCode;
                var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, varifyUrl);
```

and in my email body i am sending link like this

```
 "<br/> <br/> <a href = '" + link +"&expire="+tokenModel.ExpiresOn+"&token="+tokenModel.CreateToken+"'>Reset link</a> <br/><br/>" +
```

which does not to work as expected. anyone can help me achieve this, also i am not using core, only mvc5.

**Edit** this is my controller where i am recieving link values

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id, DateTime expire, string token)
```

while clicking on link gives **A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)** error.

Comment: what is not working, what error are you getting ?

Comment: creating a link like`http://localhost/E_HealthCare_Web/Account/ResetPassword/e4557dfd-715b-44d0-a35b-3e4eaa4c2fea&expire=7/6/2022%2012:42:58%20PM&token=627E65B98E0F9640677119A2A05AF78FEE72D8CDA521D7FCA466E439A3967AE6` which gives **A potentially dangerous Request.Path value** as error while opening the link. also i am not sure if link should be this way

Comment: port no is missing after localhost from your url

Comment: that works fine because i have added my project to iis by creating virtual path

Comment: i think date is the problem, you need to change the format of date for passing as query parameter, you should not use / character

Comment: You should not have the expiry date appended in the URL... Hacker would modify the date in the URL and reset the password even for expired token... Ideally you should store the resetCode and expiry in the database (you don't need token) against the userid and check the expiry when user tries to reset the password by clicking the link. and for the expired resetCode you should not allow the password reset.

Comment: @chetan that makes sense. thank you for suggestion i'll do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, instead of adding expiration token query parameters with URL manage this at your method action level i.e.

1. You already have the information that which login is going to this URL. All you have to do is that before sending this URL via email, make a separate temp table that will have user ID, reset password URL path, created date/time column (this column will mange the data/time when you send the URL to the user for password reset) and active/Iactive status column.
2. Now at code level when this particular URL is hit by user, first get the active row only entry against this URL & user ID and get the created date/time column value.
3. Check the difference between the active created date/time column and current date/time.
4. if difference between two dates is more than 24hr send expiration response otherwise change the password.
5. Mark that entry as inactive.
6. Know that against each user the active entry in this new table exist only when user request's password reset, otherwise all existing entries are marked as inactive.
7. You can delete instead of active/inactive as well. this is temp table.